# Trigger event on background image load

Tags: jquery

Is there a way, using jQuery, to trigger an event on load of a CSS background image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you could do it like this,

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bmhf/)

```
$('<img>').load(function(){
    // make sure to bind the load event BEFORE setting the "src"
    alert('image loaded');
}).attr('src',function(){
    var imgUrl = $('body').css('background-image');
    imgUrl = imgUrl .substring(4, imgUrl .length-1);
    return imgUrl;
}).each(function() {
    // fail-safe for cached images which sometimes don't trigger "load" events
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: Would this wait until the image is loaded or until there is a return on the value of the 'background-image' property?

Comment: actually what happened there is it will wait for the image to load... in this case the background image of the body tag...

Comment: That's a pretty neat trick.  How does it work?  I can't figure out what $('<img>') is targeting...

Comment: @sequoia mcdowell - you got the wrong link. It's a [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event)

Comment: The demo is broken based on Fresheyeball's notes I've fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/7bmhf/

Comment: @Squirkle $("<img>") is not targeting, it's creating. $() is overloaded, if you pass it an HTML string instead of a CSS-selector, jQuery will create that bit of HTML for you.

Comment: I dont get the image loaded alert in the demo.  No JS errors.  The image is visible so no sure why the callback isn't firing?

Comment: @iltdev - the original code was not in the right order and omitted some some fail-safe checking for cached images.  See updated answer.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to use `.one('load', ...)` to avoid double processing?

Comment: There seems to be an issue here, we should change the code to :
`imgUrl = imgUrl .substring(5, imgUrl .length-2); `

Comment: hmm, so it creates a second, off-document copy of the background image, and waits for that to load, and basically presumes that when that one is loaded, the background image will also be loaded..

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<img>').attr('src',function(){
    var imgUrl = $('#body').css('background-image');
    imgUrl = imgUrl .substring(5, imgUrl .length-2);
    return imgUrl;
}).load(function(){
    //Do Something
});
```

Could not help but notice that the above code does not work in fiddle. Looks like its because it returns "url('/img-path.jpg')" instead of just "/img-path.jpg".

However this method still fails in IE. Anyone have an ie fix?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem with IE is cache: http://www.witheringtree.com/2009/05/image-load-event-binding-with-ie-using-jquery/

so you could try this:

```
$(”).attr({src: src + ‘?random=’ + (new Date()).getTime()}).load(function (){
  //custom code here....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img, .hasBGI').css('opacity',0)

$('.hasBGI').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
        $bgi = $('<img src="'+/*folderFix*/$this.css('backgroundImage')+'">')
        // $bgi.css(/*hiddingStyle*/)
        $('body').append($bgi)
        $bgi.load(function(){
            $(this).remove()
            $this.animate({opacity:1})
        })
})
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:1})
})
```

})

Comment: My intention was to imagesSmoothLoad