# jQuery: Wait for background to load and then trigger an animation

Tags: jquery, background, load

As the title suggests, what i am trying to do is wait for the body background image to load and then animate a couple of things in the page.

The background image is set as a background through CSS.

I found this solution but it doesn't seem to work for me [Trigger event on background image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281651/trigger-event-on-background-image-load) (throws an error)

Comment: What error? The solution sounds like what you need.

Comment: Actually it's not an error it's a warning that says Warning: Unexpected token in attribute selector: '!'.
And the alert never shows up

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use your animation code in

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    //initialize after images are loaded  
});
```

instead of document-ready construction

Comment: yeah that could work, thing is that solution is waiting for all the images to be loaded. I just want to trigger the animation of some elements as soon as the page background image is loaded.