# Fade In a Div with background image after loading

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to fade in a `div` which has an inline background image in it.

I've tried it on images on page load, but how can we achieve that effect with background images in a `div`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285809/how-can-i-tell-when-a-css-background-image-has-loaded-is-an-event-fired

Comment: no that dosen't answer my question.

Comment: there is no way AFAIK to detect when the background image loaded.. so the solution there is to make use of another load event technique

Answer (score 3):

You Can Use a jQuery plugin called [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) that can detect when background images have downloaded.

```
$('selector').waitForImages({
    finished:function(){$(this).slideUp();},
    waitForAll:true
});
```

Comment: I was talking about the background image on div.

Comment: That code won't care about background images. You need to read the project's documentation closer.

Comment: @alex set waitForAll: true and background images will be included. Answer edited.

Comment: waitForImages is great

Answer (score 2):

The second answer from the Question linked in the comments, [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285809/how-can-i-tell-when-a-css-background-image-has-loaded-is-an-event-fired), provides a solution where you load a background-image to an image tag, then when it's ready you inject the image into a div. Here is an example similar, yet different:

html:

```
<img src="http://www.modernmythmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Iron-Man-wallpaper-2-2032-e1367196003357.jpg" id="dummy" style="display:none;" alt="" />
<div id="pic" style="height:100px;width:100px;display:none;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#dummy').ready(function() {
    $('#pic').css('background-image','url(http://www.modernmythmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Iron-Man-wallpaper-2-2032-e1367196003357.jpg)');
    $('#pic').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

With live preview here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unUc8/2/).

Hopefully this works better for you!

Comment: hey buddy i need it to fade in after image has been loaded.thanks.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer Good call. I updated my answer to be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I suggest also placing the background url to the div. You probaly can do that when you put together the template, whilst the JS method takes some resource:   
http://jsfiddle.net/unUc8/8/. I also took the liberty of removing the image after the load, minimizing the DOMsize (allthough one might argue about the CPU it takes to remove them)

Comment: Updated the answer from `div#id` to `#id`. When using id's, it can use `getElementById()`, when you add the div, it also has to test if it is a div, and it can no longer use the fast functions :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Animation will load a canvas context that allows for [this and more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas).

[Here](http://cssnerd.com/2012/04/03/jquery-like-pure-css3-image-fade-in/) is the CSS demo of the animation.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="mg" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920/); display:none; width:1920px; height:1920px;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var elem   = $('#mg'),
    bgImg  = elem.css('background-image'),
    imgUrl = bgImg.indexOf('"')!=-1 ? 
             bgImg.replace('url("','').replace('")','') : 
             bgImg.replace('url(','').replace(')',''),

     nwImg = new Image();
     nwImg.src = imgUrl;

nwImg.onload = function() {
    elem.fadeIn('fast');
}

nwImg.onerror = function() {
    alert('error');
}
```

**JsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/EZg36/8/

If you change the URL incorrectly, you will see that the error message (for example: background-image:url(hERRRttp://lorempixel.com/1920/1920/);)

Comment: @Martijn I dont know, no special reason :)