# Angular - detect when background-image has loaded

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, dom

[angular (load) mehtod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687/detect-when-image-has-loaded-in-img-tag) can detect img tag has loaded.

When the element is a `DIV` and has a background image attribute, can detect the image has loaded?

```
div {
    background-image: url(https://image.jpg)
}

<div (load)="isLoad()"> //the function isLoad() is not work
```

Comment: Check in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285809/how-can-i-tell-when-a-css-background-image-has-loaded-is-an-event-fired/6285898

Comment: Try to Use This Plugin..

https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/