# removing image tag from memory

Tags: jquery

I have seen some code to check if a background image on a div is loaded. What they are doing is adding a img tag to memory but storing it in a variable and using that to see if the image is loaded with the load event. My question is does the $img tag stay in memory and how would I be able to remove that tag when the load event has been called.

```
  var $div = $('div'),
  bg = $div.css('background-image');
  if (bg) {
    var src = bg.replace(/(^url\()|(\)$|[\"\'])/g, ''),
      $img = $('<img>').attr('src', src).on('load', function() {
        // do something, maybe:
        $div.fadeIn();
      });
  }
});
```

[I got this code above from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove elements with [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). In your case the newly created `<img>` element is cached in the `$img` variable. So when you want to remove it you just do:

```
$img.remove();
```

To release the variable from memory you can use:

```
delete $img;
```

Although that isn't really necessary if the variable scope is not global as the javascript garbage collector will take care of that for you.

Also [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is deprecated and unreliable across browsers, so using it is discouraged. From jQuery docs:

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> • It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>   • It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>   before
>   • It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>   • Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

One alternative to load is [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/797120/7176db676f1e0e20d7c23933f9fc655c2f120c58).

Comment: Thanks Spider, so what should I use instead of load? I thought remove only worked for jquery elements when they were part of the dom meaning appended then use remove. I didn't know you could use it for object in memory.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct about that. I missed the fact that you were not injecting the new element into the DOM. One alternative to `load` is [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/797120/7176db676f1e0e20d7c23933f9fc655c2f120c58) which takes care of the browser cache issues, but I'm not sure there's a 100% reliable cross-browser solution for this. As for releasing the variable allocated memory you can use `delete $img;`.

Answer (score 0):

### Leave it on Garbage Collector, otherwise

Just set the `$img` variable `null`, like

```
$img=null;
```

Actually `$img.remove();` won't do that as mentioned in the comment by someone and also you don't have to worry about it because javascript [Garbage Collector](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_03.htm) will do it for you and `delete` will work only if you declare the variable without `var` keyword. In this case of `$img=null` just makes the variable an empty `null` object.

[Example using null](http://jsfiddle.net/qe4nx/) and [Example using .remove()](http://jsfiddle.net/qe4nx/1/).

Comment: It looks like you are wrong. If you run [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qe4nx/9/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qe4nx/10/) during 1 hour, the memory consumption is stable on the first one and is increasing on the second one.

Comment: @benweet, So, can you exactly tell on what i'm wrong, which argument ?

Comment: The test I've set up shows that you have to worry about `$img.remove();`.

Comment: @benweet, SO, you are telling that garbage collection won't clean the mess, right ?

Comment: The test has been running for 2 hours now. The first window takes between 80MB and 90MB. The second window is taking 173MB now and is going bigger. I'm not 100% sure it won't be garbage collected but I have some serious doubts.

Comment: @benweet, So, let me know when you become doubtless so I can change/delete my answer and can think about it differently and need to learn from the beginning.

Comment: After a few hours, the first window takes 88MB and the second 270MB. So I can tell that Chrome 28.0.1500.95 on OSX 10.8.4 doesn't collect elements created with `$('<img>')`.