# Check if a background image is loaded, Responsive Edition

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I have set a background image to the body tag (large pic) and I want to fade it in once loaded  (since the image is large, it would roll in when loading).

I have seen this answer that basically uses a hidden img tag and leverage the browser cache: [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

This is great for a fixed-layout website, but what about a responsive site? I don't want to load all 3 background images at the same time, but I'd want to be able to select the one that has to be loaded in the hidden img tag.

See site here: http://jll.is

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

First apply `opacity:0` to the image, this will prevent it from being showed.
And put your fade in effect using jquery like this

```
$('#imgid').load(function(){

Fade in effect

});
```

Comment: Dont use bg image then. You can not do it like that.