# Event in Dart that shows when all the background images of divs are loaded?

Tags: html, dom, dart

on what event should i listen to see when are the all background-images loaded?

It would be cool also to specify which background Images I want to put as a preloader option?

```
#preloader{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
```

Here is basic div that I use to cover my entire page. Once all the background images are loaded, or the ones that I prefer I would like to make this preloader div hidden with some transitions.

Comment: What are trying right now?  Can you post some code?

Comment: code updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an event fired when a background image has finished loading; however if you can convert them to normal `<img>` tags, you can use the `onload` events.

There's a little more info in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/25124).