# affect which dom-elements load first on siteload

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how I could affect which elements in my body load first. To my problem: I have something like a curtain (a `<div>` with `background-image`) as overlay on my site, and if the page is loaded it fires a function to `.animate()` out that curtain. After that you see the page with all elements (which are a lot).

When I'm entering my site, I see some of the elements behind that curtain because they are faster loaded than the background image of my div.

My markup is like that:

```
<body>
   <div id="curtain"></div>
   <!-- after that all other elements -->
</body>
```

As you can see I've put the curtain div as first element in the body, but it does not work.

How can I guarantee that `#curtain` is loaded first and then all other elements, that I won't see them before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you should wrap all that other elements with a parent container, to hide them by default with javascript. Make sure, you do it with javascript, because if someone hasn't javascript activated and you would do it with css, they probably see nothing.

You could then use javascript again, to set a timeout when the curtain went off the screen or a more safer way, [check if the image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/2535835) and then fire your animate function.