# jQuery animation on selected img working locally but not remotely

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagesloaded

I have the following animated elements in a tile that (visually) rotate on their z-axis... it is on the following page...

http://sthera.com/modelos.php

and it is coded thus (a bit brute-forced, if a more elegant solution come to mind it would also be appreciated)...

```
$(window).load(function () {
    imagesLoaded('.fixedWidth', function () {
        console.log("animation starting3");
        var locationClean = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        var loc = locationClean.split('sthera/')[1];
        //alert (loc);

        if (loc == 'modelos.php' || loc == 'aislar.php') {

            //alert ("animation starting2");

            var duration = 300;
            var imgWidth = 123;
            var delayFactor = 60;
            var marginLeft = imgWidth / 2;
            //establecemos los valores de inicio
            $(".a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6, .a7").css({
                'width': '0px',
                    'margin-left': marginLeft + 'px',
                    'opacity': '0'
            });
            $(".c1, .c2, .c3, .c4, .c5, .c6, .c7").css({
                'opacity': '0'
            });

            $(".a1").delay(1 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c1").delay(1 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a2").delay(2 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c2").delay(2 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a3").delay(3 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c3").delay(3 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a4").delay(4 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c4").delay(4 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a5").delay(5 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c5").delay(5 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a6").delay(6 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c6").delay(6 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

            $(".a7").delay(7 * delayFactor).animate({
                'width': imgWidth + 'px',
                    'margin-left': '0px',
                    'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);
            $(".c7").delay(7 * delayFactor + duration).animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, duration);

        }

    });
}); //end animation()
//JavaScript Document
```

where `.a1 ... .a7` are classed images.

This code runs perfectly in my local test server but not remotely...

I thought the problem might have something to do with the images not being loaded by the time $(document).ready... ran so I used the imagesLoaded plugin recommended by another user... [Preload images with JQuery to get dominant colour of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252540/preload-images-with-jquery-to-get-dominant-colour-of-image) ... didn´t work though. The code is being run after the images load but apparently that wasn't the issue.

(many) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just noticed, you used `animate2.js` instead of `animate.js`. The code you've posted above is on `animate.js`. - just an observation.

Comment: Are you getting the `console.log("animation starting3");` in your console? I'm wondering if the script is running at all. Also what does `loc` end up being? I see you commented out the alert, maybe the server's url structure is different from the local one and nothing is running because `loc` is wrong or empty.

Comment: Thanks... @dunli the code I posted is in animate.js, the codes are very similar...

Comment: @JupiterPalace I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it and the question could be closed. Also, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the `console.log("animation starting3");` in your console? I'm wondering if the script is running at all. Also what does `loc` end up being? I see you commented out the alert, maybe the server's url structure is different from the local one and nothing is running because `loc` is wrong or empty.