# Change background image onclick with easing

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, easing

I am implementing a site and I would like to change background images on click but with ease, like fade in fade out or whatever.

The onclick part is implemented with Jquery but I am struggling with the easing part.

I have searched the Web for this but every solution is using a div only in a small part of the page.

The problem for me is that I use these divs as a whole page, 100% width and height and I have content in front of the divs.

I thought about using sprites and animate the background position but that doesn't help because I want my page to be responsive and I have percentage on background url and sprites need you to declare fixed width (correct me if I'm wrong).

Also I must add that behind the divs there is an other div, so changing opacity solution can't help. I am implementing a site like this: http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxynote3-gear/

HTML:

```
<div class="Page" id="feauture3">
    <div id="feauture3_content">
        <div id="feauture3_1"><strong>Menu1</strong></div>
        <div id="feauture3_2"><strong>Menu2</strong></div>
        <div id="feauture3_3"><strong>Menu3</strong></div>
        <div id="feauture3_4"><strong>Menu4</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#feauture3_1:hover {
        background-color:#f2af95;
        cursor:pointer;
}

#feauture3_2:hover {
        background-color:#f2af95;
        cursor:pointer;
}

#feauture3_3:hover {
        background-color:#f2af95;
        cursor:pointer;
}

#feauture3_4:hover {
        background-color:#f2af95;
        cursor:pointer;
}

#feauture3 {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: url('http://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-z800e/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-02.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
        left:0; 
        background-size: cover;
        background-color:#e18764;
        color:red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $("#feauture3_1").click(function(){
       $("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("http://www.motorcyclespecs.co.za/Gallery%20B/Kawasaki%20Ninja%20650R%2013.jpg")');
    });

    $("#feauture3_2").click(function(){
        $("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31700000/HOT-BABE-KAWASAKI-Z1000-motorcycles-31778270-1920-1200.jpg")')
    });

    $("#feauture3_3").click(function(){
        $("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("http://b296d35169b22ec514a7-3f0e5c3ce41f2ca4459ddb89d451f8d9.r21.cf2.rackcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Kawasaki-Z1-by-Ac-Sanctuary-.jpg")')
    });

    $("#feauture3_4").click(function(){
        $("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ar4zyO_Ws4M/UekF8jk7nRI/AAAAAAAA1q4/ugQZlRGTLkk/s1600/Kawasaki-Z-1000-.jpg")')
    });

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pWhN/1/

Thanks for your time.

**Edit: I finally used a simple $`("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("image")')` and set a `background-color` to the whole div that matches the images(the real project dont have motorcycles as images). This was quite acceptable and I used this solution.**

Comment: Would you consider using third party plugins?

Comment: It would be too complicated right now cause the real project is very big and now its online and I cant deploy this from the start. I finally used a simple 
$("#feauture3").css('background-image','url("image")')
and set a background-color to the whole div that matches the images(the real project dont have motorcycles as images). This was quite acceptable and I used it.

Answer (score 2):

How about css transitions ?

```
#feauture3 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-z800e/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-02.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    left:0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#e18764;
    color:red;
    -webkit-transition:all 1.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pWhN/3/)

Comment: Nice answer but flashes the image onclick. I would like a perfect transition! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, it flashes because your CSS and jquery are not optimized. I just gave you and idea of how it can work. It's up to you how you use it.

Comment: No it flashes because it requests an image link :) If nothing better shows up I will use this.

Comment: I used finally used transitions, but check my edit in original post to what I did.

Answer (score 0):

We can divide this problems into several parts:

1. How to add easing or fading effects to images answer is using CSS 3

   ```
   #feauture3 {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: url('http://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-z800e/2013-kawasaki-ninja-z800-02.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
   left:0; 
   background-size: cover;
   background-color:#e18764;
   color:red;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000); 
       transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000);
   }
   ```

2. How detect that image loaded and add src answer is using js hack

```
$("<img>").attr('src', 'http://picture.de/image.png').load(function() {
     $(this).remove();
     $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://picture.de/image.png)');
});
```

Play with [css3 easing fading](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)

Question about image loading [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Comment: Cant understand how the js hack can apply on my code though I need the transition not to flash.

Comment: because before loading background image user can't see transition effect, so you must apply src attribute after browser complete loading  image. Simple if user haven't image in cache he can't see transition first time

Comment: No you dont understand. I dont use an image tag to use the code you pasted.

Comment: This img created only to preload image. I don't use this image!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to your features:

```
    $("#feauture3_2").click(function(){
    $("#feauture3").css({
        'background-image' :  'url("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31700000/HOT-BABE-KAWASAKI-Z1000-motorcycles-31778270-1920-1200.jpg")',
        'opacity': 0
    })
    .animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 800);
});
```

Just apply that to each click event.

Comment: Nice answer but I forgot to tell that i have other divs down from the div I want to change its background. So this shows the previous div. I am implementing a site like this.

http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxynote3-gear/

Comment: Just specify your target. Same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/9pWhN/6/

Add `.fadeOut()` before image change, and then `.fadeIn()` again with `setTimeout()`.

#### JQUERY

```
$("#feauture3_1").click(function(){
   $("#feauture3").fadeOut(1000);
   setTimeout(function() {
       $("#feauture3")
           .css('background-image','url("http://www.motorcyclespecs.co.za/Gallery%20B/Kawasaki%20Ninja%20650R%2013.jpg")')
           .fadeIn(1000);     
   }, 1000);       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix - test for proper loading once both the external images loaded -

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var img1 = 'http://www.motorcyclespecs.co.za/Gallery%20B/Kawasaki%20Ninja%20650R%2013.jpg',
      img2 = 'http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31700000/HOT-BABE-KAWASAKI-Z1000-motorcycles-31778270-1920-1200.jpg',
      target = $('#feauture3');

      $("#feauture3_1").click(function(){
          target.fadeOut(1000, function(){
              target.css('background-image', 'url('+img1+')');  
              target.fadeIn(500);
          });
      });

      $("#feauture3_2").click(function(){
          target.fadeOut(1000, function(){
              target.css('background-image', 'url('+img2+')');  
              target.fadeIn(500);
          });
      });
```

});

Comment: thanks, but it shows the div behind the div that i want to change its background. Check the link on my question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can handle the background color also along with the bg image from JQuery

Comment: Actually for your requirement i suggest you to go with a carousel plugin

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be what you are looking for -

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg7

Loading all the images on top of each other before transitioning them will not create the 'flash' you are talking about.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this link yesterday, will give it a try. though its supposed to have content in front of the image thats why I use background-image url.

Comment: If the div is going to be the parent div, it shouldn't matter if you have the images displaying regularly rather than as a background image