# Animate when the first image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate an element only when this element is loaded ( with the background ). I tryed this but doesn't work:

CSS:

```
#topimg{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(../img/bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topimg"> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#topimg').load(function() {
   $('#topimg').css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 1500});
});
```

Comment: doesnt work how? doesnt animate, or animates before the element is fully loaded?

Comment: @Banana animate before the element is fully loaded.

Comment: since images are only being loaded once, and stored in the browser cache for later use, there is a good trick [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22788887/3406576) by adeneo. basically you load the backgound image into an `img` element, and when the img is loaded then the image already exists and is loaded for the background of your div as well.