# React JS show component after resources loaded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I'm using React and I have big landing image and I wanted to show the component when the img is ready. You can see this screenshot :
[image]

[image: Loaded but img not done yet]

The Content showed but the image still loading. I want it to show when the image is ready. I've already use lazy loading but it doesn't work. Here's my code :

Landing.jsx

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react"
import Loading from "./Loading"
const Content = lazy(() => import("./Content"))

export default class Landing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Content />
      </Suspense>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the content showed while the image still loading. You can see at the screenshot it still loaded half.

Comment: Can you post your "./Content"?

Comment: That could be a long code. It's just a content component, can be anything. If u asking where did I call the img source, it was on my css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onLoad` to remove the loading screen.

```
<img src="some/path" alt="hello" onLoad={() => this.setState({isLoading: false})} />
```

onLoad event will fire when the image is loaded, you can use this concept to create what you want since you can't do that by just using suspense, or you can just use something like [react-on-images-loaded](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-on-images-loaded).

in your case since it's a background image you can adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22788887/10193531) to be used in react.