# How to call function after the background image loads using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new in javascript and php.

My body page has a link of a background image.
I have a div (`div.loader`) and in my js code, I have a variable `var countdown = 15`.When my countdown is 0, it will add a class `loaded` to my div but I don't know how long the image will load and also the images load so slow (for me).
So I want to call a function that will add a class `loaded` if the image loaded completely. (here's the link of my website loader: acromix.net16.net)

How do I call a function after the background image loads using javascript or php?
(no extensions or plugins)

(This might be a duplicate but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded) (jquery,plugins) is not answering my question)

Comment: Show some code please! It will be better for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in pure javasciprt.

```js
var backgroundImageUrl = "backgorundImageName.jpg";

// checking if image is already there in cache 
if (sessionStorage.getItem(backgroundImageUrl)) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImageUrl + "')";
} else {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = backgroundImageUrl;
  img.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backgroundImageUrl + "')";
    sessionStorage.setItem(backgroundImageUrl, true);
    img = undefined;
  };

}
```

I have used `sessionStorage` to track if the image is already in the cache or not. `onload` won't fire if image is already present in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about javascript then you can use the onload() event function in the body tag of html.

Javascript method:

```
<script>
function callFunc()
{
  //call your another function here
}
</script>

<body onload="callFunc()">

</body>
```

And if you are thinking to use jquery then call that function in

```
$(function(){
  //your function to be called
})
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching `eventListener` or `onload` event to your image object and then perform whatever you are trying to do?

```
object.addEventListener("load", myScript);
```

OR

```
object.onload=function(){myScript};
```

You should create image objects in javascript and define their src. and then use the event to do whatever you are trying to do .

Here is one example

```
var imageName = new Image();
imageName.src = "imageName.jpg";
imageName.onload = function()
{
//do your work here
};
```