# Why is this difference in calculations? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

There is a difference when you call function in `document.ready` calculation or `resize function`

There is a white border when the page loads calculation is not correct ...

[image]

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();   
    var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
    console.log('stanga:',stanga);
    var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
    console.log('dreapta:',dreapta);
    var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
    console.log('total:',contentwh);
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh);
    $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh);
    $('.continut').css('width',contentwh);

    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();   
        var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
        console.log('stanga-resize:',stanga);
        var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
        console.log('dreapta-resize:',dreapta);
        var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
        console.log('total-resize:',contentwh);
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh);
        $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh);
        $('.continut').css('width',contentwh);
    }
});
```

Basically I used the same code and document.ready but also according to resize and unfortunately goes.

I did manual calculation on a 1366 px and ought to get a 669px width (good value) and I am 657px sites.

Does anyone know why this difference appears to 12px?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have closing for either for doc ready or for resize.

Comment: Why not just use `width: 47.6%;` for `#main-content`?

Answer (score 0):

-edit

The issue lies with the .right node max-width property disabling this causes the page to load the dimensions correctly **however** the algorithm with the node resizing is not being run correctly on document ready.
The page loads correctly after re-sizing the page.

My best guess for this next issue is that the OP did not provide enough code to fully diagnose his issue; but, i am positive that the code on ready is not executing correctly.
Run each variable in console and edit your question to provide the answers please.

Onload values:

```
window: 1903
custom2.js:89 
stanga: 260
custom2.js:91 
dreapta: 609
custom2.js:93 
total: 1034
```

After resize:

```
window: 1918
custom2.js:156 
stanga-resize: 260
custom2.js:158 
dreapta-resize: 614
custom2.js:160 
total-resize: 1044
custom2.js:154 
window: 1920
custom2.js:156 
stanga-resize: 260
custom2.js:158 
dreapta-resize: 614
custom2.js:160 
total-resize: 1046
```

Your resize event is being triggered twice, thats a problem of its own, but eventually it resolves the correct values.

Comment: You mean the problem is the background image of secondary? ... I do not think the problem is that the width is too small

Comment: One second let me look again. what web browser are you using?

Comment: This works fine in google chrome: Version 44.0.2403.155 m

Comment: Issue happens in: Opera 31.0

Comment: really do not know how to solve this problem ... I have carefully studied the problem and found a solution but

Comment: issue happens in: Firefox 40.0.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87490/discussion-between-cristi-and-richard-grant).

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Windows as OS aren't you?

The problem is that on load, you have a scrollbar.So when you are making you calculs, some element have a smaller width. Later, the scrollbar dispear and the white gap appear.

Quick fix would be to add `overflow:hidden` on the body then make your calculs. Afterward, you can remove the overflow hidden.

Note that the problem also appear when you resize the window below a certain height.

Comment: you mean to add 'body {overfow: hidden;}'?

Comment: Thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might need to load the background image asynchronus, catch an event when loading is done, and then make calculations. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  asyncLoad('.yourElement');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  doCalculations('.yourElement');
});

var asyncLoad = function(elem) {
  var imgCSS = elem.css('background-image');
  var imgSrc = imgCSS.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
  $('<img/>').attr('src', imgSrc).load(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    elem.css('background-image', imgCSS);
    doCalculations(elem);
  });
});

var doCalculations = function(elem) {
  var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();   
  var stanga = jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
  var dreapta = jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
  var contentwh = windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
  $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh);
  $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh);
  $('.continut').css('width',contentwh);
}
```

You might need to change the function to catch an array of images and do something when the last is done loading, but I hope the idea of 'Async loading' is well explained.

As explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded) the function loads an image, and then it uses the same image as background-image for your element, and the browser is smart enough to not load that image twice.