# How to check if background img failed to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title says. I want to be able to determine if a background img failed to load. I looked around and seen loads of information but sadly cant get any of them to work for me.

I seen a pretty good one describing to use a plugin called **waitForImages** located: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

I cant seem to get the failed to load work. Now, if someone has a better way im all open! As long as i can get an alert to say it failed. I pushed in a fake URL so it should come back with link not working.

Code:

```
$("#cover-art").css("background-image", 'url("/assets/img/cover-adio.png")');

$('#cover-art').waitForImages(function() {
    alert('All images have loaded.');
}, function(loaded, count, success) {
   alert(loaded + ' of ' + count + ' images has ' + (success ? 'loaded' : 'failed to load') +  '.');
   $(this).addClass('loaded');
});
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: I tried most of them but they are for img tag not background img? If they are for background img also, not sure how to connect it to that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to check given url exists with client side javascript. But you can try this trick.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="mydiv" style="background-image:url('foo.png')">
      <img id="foo_img" src="foo.png" style="display:none;">
      
      <p>Status:<span id="result"></span></p>
    </div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgtowatch = document.getElementById("foo_img");
    var events = ["load", "error"];

    events.forEach(function(ev){
    imgtowatch.addEventListener(ev, function(){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ev;
    });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

then try with

```
`style="background-image:url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png')`
```

and

```
src='http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('<img/>').load("/assets/img/cover-audio.png", function(res, status, xhr) {
    if(status == "error"){
         alert("Image not loaded");
    }
    else{
         $(this).remove(); 
         $("#cover-art").css('background-image', 'url(/assets/img/cover-adio.png)');
    }
});
```

Here's a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxn1tLd8/)

Credits: [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/7224597)

Comment: This looks so promising but it always gets a status of success? Not sure why? I console logged status and always comes back with success. When the location i put in doesnt exist?

Comment: @irishwill200 Well that sounds weird. The fiddle works fine if I change the URL.

Comment: If i use your fiddle code it works, but as soon as i change the code to suit my local image on the server it comes back with success? Even when the url is fake ._.

Comment: @irishwill200 Try to debug it. You don't see any errors in the console whatsoever?

Comment: No errors coming up, such a shame it doesnt work. Thanks though!