# Call a component function when page completely load in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I got an angular 10 app that first start a login page. But before presenting the login fields, I need to check the presence of the web service and check if the app is currently in maintenance. So I need to call a function in my `login.component.ts` file but when all the contents of the page will be loaded and displayed.

I tried this:

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
   if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.NetworkTest();
   }
 });
```

in my constructor but, it's called a little too early and my main background image is not displayed.
Any advice for me?

I also tried ngAfterViewInit with the same result.

Thanks

UDATE1:
It is normal that in the NavigationEnd event the binding do not work? The properties is change in background, but the view is not updated.

Comment: Is the only issue the background image not being loaded completely..?

Comment: Maybe put the main background image in the index.html and make sure your login.component doesn't have a background that will obscure any part of the main image.

Comment: No, some DIV hidden with ngif are not hidden yet

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterViewInit` seems a good place for your needs.
To make sure background is displayed you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334123/wait-for-background-image-css-style-to-fully-load).

To handle displaying login form I suggest creating a flag. Set it to true only if web service is running.
TS: `let isWebServiceRunning = false;`
HTML: `<div *ngIf="isWebServiceRunning">Login Form</div>`