# MutationObserver and DOM timings

Tags: javascript, dom, timing, mutation-observers

I am using said [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes on an `HTMLElement`.

I dynamically add children to a `div` and the observer does a nice job at executing the provided callback anytime changes are detected in the `div`'s tree.

I am adding the children all together (by mounting a React component) and there is an action that I need to perform only when I know that all of them are added; if I perform that action also before all the children are added to the DOM, then I would irreparably mess everything up.

The observer possibly would run the callback a bunch of times within a fraction of a second just because I added a bunch of children, so a possible solution would be to set a timeout for this particular action.

Now since the action is vital for the interactivity of the page I need to wait as little as possible.

My question is: is there an order of magnitude for the time needed to add a handful of children to an element? Something like 1ms, 100ms or 1 second? How long is it safe to wait?
But also: are you aware of any other possible solution to the problem?

PS: my question is a generalisation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667100/mutationobserver-callback-only-when-all-resources-have-loaded), which has been solved by checking for the appearance of a particular entity (a `background-image`), but I am working with a reusable custom hook and waiting for the appearance of an element that could be an `input` as it could be a `button` and by the way it would not be the only one of its type among the children being added to the `div`, nor it is granted that it will be present on the DOM once all the children are added. I just need to check for its presence once all the children are added and that's it. A different approach is needed.

Comment: You can add all children in just one DOM mutation by using `parentElem.append(...children)`

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunately I think that appending is not an option. I am writing a reusable hook that watches for changes on the `div` but the hook is not responsible for the changes, they are made in some component outside in the wild. I need to solve the problem inside the hook.

Comment: Try requestAnimationFrame as shown in [point 10 here](/a/39332340).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm not sure how requestAnimationFrame can solve my problem. If I get it right, you can use requestAnimationFrame to tell the browser when to execute a function, rather than leaving the decision to it. It's true that I know when I want to perform my action (after all the children are added), but it's also true that I don't know when I want to perform my action (amount of time after first mutation has been observed); so I am not in the position to give instructions to the browser.

Comment: The idea was that all children are added in one event loop task, so your rAF callback will see the final state.

Comment: Oh I really needed this idea to understand the logic of the code in the answer you linked. I guess that this solution is going to work just fine, even though I don't have that much knowledge on the event loop (nor on react under the hood) to be sure that the component(s) will be mounted in a single event loop task. Anyway this seems to be the only reasonable thing to do and if you want to articulate an answer (for future readers) I would be happy to mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @wOxxOm However I can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) that a setTimeout with 0 would execute the callback at the next event cycle. How is the rAF approach any different?