# Will load event wait for background-image in css to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know if the load event in js will wait until the background-image: url() in css is loaded completely.

What is the exact behaviour in this scenario?

Comment: What do you try to do exactly ?

Comment: I'm loading background-image in css and wait for load event. After the event is fired I take a page screenshot. But sometimes the image does not load completely. I want to know if the load event will wait for the background-image property.

Comment: I'm actually using puppeteer tool for taking the screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Comment: So Aysush, will load event wait for background-image? There is no proper documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://picture.de/image.png').on('load', function() {
   $(this).remove(); // prevent memory leaks as @benweet suggested
   $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://picture.de/image.png)');
});
```

try this

for more reference:-

[How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Comment: Have you used puppeteer tool anytime before?

Comment: No but I know a little bit about it @Terminator

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you should be sure that the page is 100% loaded.

For a simple and fast result, use jQuery:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // Take the screenshot here.
});
```

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXgdJq

Comment: This is fine. But are you surr that the load will fire only after the background-image in css is loaded, not the one in  <img>. My question should actually be how to know if the background-image is loaded completely?