# Event for the load-end of dynamically added CSS files through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I use jQuery (which seems to use a glorified form of innerHTML document writing), to add a piece of HTML to the DOM:

```
    $newElem=$(HTML).appendTo($container);
```

The said HTML piece contains CSS links, which seem to load async. Images also load async.

I need some form of `load` event similar to `window.load` when async content is done fetching AND done parsing (i.e. CSS), because based on that I trigger a container resize/rearrange function, and sizing obviously depends on CSS, async images (and even async fonts but this last point is not an immediate concern for me). So how to get a proper `load` event for the DOM-added HTML?

Comment: You're correct about `.html()`. from the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/): "This method uses the browser's `innerHTML` property."

Comment: `$('img').on('load')` generally works. If you get that onto your appended images or delegate it, you should get that event firing. I am not sure if you can do the same for $('style').on('load'), but you might wanna give it a try

Comment: @user3154108 I was thinking of lumping together the `<link>` and `<img>`'s onload events into a whale of a promise; but there is at least one whale of a problem here: CSS's `content:url()`, which is the equivalent of writing an `<img>` tag in CSS... and no onload for that then. I was hoping there would be a more semantically correct way of handling this.

Comment: @Dinu aside from preloading the images from the CSS with Javascript before appending the CSS, I know of no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in "load" event that's fired when all the resources requested by the dynamically added elements are finished loading.

You can probably implement this though if you're sufficiently motivated.

There's [`waitForImages` jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), that goes through the given DOM subtree, looking for images (`<img>` tags as well as references to images in computed CSS styles). It creates an `<img>` element for each image referenced from CSS to track its load status (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)).

It doesn't support:

- `content:url()` images (should be easy to add)
- Tracking resources referenced from dynamically loaded CSS. You can use a similar approach to find all the `<link>` elements in the given subtree, and use their `load` event ([supported in all major browsers now](https://pie.gd/test/script-link-events/)) to wait until the CSS is loaded. After CSS finishes loading, run waitForImages to track the image loads.