# when background image loaded JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that has a background image that I don't know its URL and I'm using PHP to get URL from the server and show it on my page using the `style` attribute. I want to do some stuff when that background image loaded completely.

I already tried this but it doesn't work:

```js
$('<img>').attr('src').on('load', function() {
 // My codes
});
```

Comment: Elyas try look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351304/2943218

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen Thanks, but I don't have my URL and user will give me that and I am using PHP to add some style to my div,

Comment: I generally use the accepted answer approach from the above link.

Comment: If you can assign the image URL to background via styles, then you can use it to assign it to the image `src` attribute in the script.