# How to not execute any javascript untill all CSS background images will be downloaded, cached and displayed?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, gsap

I have animated display ads, some of page elements are huge images provided in styles inside header of index.html as `background-image: url('huge-image.png');` Is there any elegant method to prevent the execution of javascript animation library (greensock gsap) until all such assets will be displayed?

Comment: You can use onload attribute on body tag to call a function  or you can use jQuery $(document).ready() function

Comment: @Vinayak - Does the window `load` event wait for **background** images? (`ready` **certainly** doesn't.)

Comment: This post has relevant information about how you can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: @PalomaEscribano - No, that doesn't wait for images (not even foreground ones, much less background ones).

Comment: @Vinayak - It does look like `load` waits for background images. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `window` `load` event may wait for background images. The [spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-load) says it has to be fired after **all** dependent resources are loaded, and a quick experiment suggests that includes background images. So

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // All loaded now.
});
```

If I'm mistaken, though, here's a fallback:

I don't know if it's *elegant*, but since I can't find anything suggesting there's an event for a background image having loaded, you could use zero-height `img` elements with the same URLs and detect when *those* load; at that point, the image should be in cache and available to use as the background.

Assuming you have an array of the image names in `imageNames`:

```
let loaded = 0;
function imgLoadedOrFailed() {
    if (++loaded === imageNames.length) {
        // They're all loaded now!
    }
}
imageNames.forEach(name => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = imgLoadedOrFailed;
    img.onerror = imgLoadedOrFailed;
    img.src = name;
});
```

Comment: @user2401543 - In what way? IE11 definitely has `forEach`. It doesn't have arrow functions if that's what you mean...

Answer (score -1):

I think onload attribute on body tag can Help you

```
<body onload="fun()">
```

And then you can wrap up your javascript in the fun() function

```
function fun(){
 // Your Code goes here
}
```

Or in case it doesn't work

You can use setTimeout function to atleast wait for some time like about 10 seconds

Like this-

```
setTimeout(()=>{
 // Your Code goes here
}, 10000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
```

> I hope It Helped You

Comment: `load` does indeed look like it waits for background images. FWIW, though, I'd remove the `setTimeout`. For all you know, the images take more than five seconds to load. Race conditions like that are generally poor practice.