# Javascript - Event listener for when all elements of class are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener, event-listener

Is there a way in Javascript to execute code once every element of type/class/tag etc. has been loaded?

Something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test").addEventListener("onload", ()=> { executeStuffHere(); });
```

If not, is there a similar way to do this for images? (Execute code once all images have been loaded)

Comment: Use `.addEventListener("load"`

Comment: and `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery/800010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a loop. You could make a count of the number of images, then decrement each time an image loads. Inside the callback, call the final function once the count gets to 0.

```
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
let imagesLeft = images.length;
for (const image of images) {
  image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    imagesLeft--;
    if (imagesLeft === 0) executeStuffHere();
  });
}
```

Note that `.addEventListener("onload"` will not work. You must use `load`.

You could also add error listeners if you want `executeStuffHere` to run once everything is finished, even if some errored.

If some images might already be loaded, [check if they're `.complete`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977898) first before adding the listener (and if they are, decrement).

Comment: Hi! Just a quick question, does this work for other elements too? I realised I don't have images, I have `div`s with `background-image`s. So far I've had no luck with this method, but I don't think it's a problem with your code, maybe just the way I'm using it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057990 Only option looks to be to use `src` instead on an image, then change to `background-image` on the `<div>` once the image loads

Answer (score 0):

First you wait for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) or ensure that [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `interactive` or `loaded`, then select all nodes maching the criteria you want, loop over them, and execute the code. The method `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which you can [coerce into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

The main thing to note here is you're not waiting for each node to load. You're waiting for the whole document to load and then iterating through the DOM tree.

```js
const fireOnAllYeses = () => {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.yes')).forEach(domNode => {
    
    //  execute code here
    console.log( domNode.innerText );
    
  });
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fireOnAllYeses);
```

```html
<main>
   <div class="yes">I am yes 1</div>
   <div class="no">I am no 1</div>
   <div class="yes">I am yes 2</div>
   <div>I am some div</div>
</main>
```