# Why can I access a cross origin image in HTML and CSS but not in a JS HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cors

I have an HTML img element like this:

```html
<img src="https://theposterdb.com/api/assets/11949" />
```

And a CSS class like this:

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://theposterdb.com/api/assets/11949);
}
```

Both of these work and display the image on my site. However when I try to do the following in JavaScript:

```js
fetch("https://theposterdb.com/api/assets/11949")
```

I get a CORS error. Why? I need to fetch the image in JS because I want to check if it was successfully loaded and otherwise display a custom alternative element.

Comment: because that's what CORS does - protects resources from unauthorised use - they are letting you use the image, but only as an image - you can, of course, use an onerror handler for the img tag to see if it was loaded

Comment: You could try `img.addEventListener("load", ...)` to check if the image is loaded.

Comment: one way to do it is to `fetch` through your server - then CORS doesn't apply - and - you can do a `HEAD` request to minimise the amount of response data - since you just want a 200 or 404 response status to check if the resource exists - what I don't understand is how you intend to fix CSS - but I guess you know what you're doing there

Comment: @Bravo I didn't know servers could distinguish a GET request by an image element from a GET request by a fetch call. Is there some meta info in the headers that makes this possible?

Comment: before going down the path you're leading yourself into ... *there is no backdoor around CORS* - the ONLY bypass is to make the request from your server ... browser requests your server, passing the URL to check, server checks, and returns a good/bad indication ... that's the only way to do it using fetch/xhr

Comment: Can you use a service worker to intercept requests made from the html img and store the img or send the blob back to main thread?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an event listener to check if the image is loaded.

HTML

```
<img id="test">
```

JS

```
let test = document.querySelector("#test")
test.addEventListener("load",()=>console.log("image was loaded!"))
test.src = "https://theposterdb.com/api/assets/11949"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The question also includes the text `I want to check if it was successfully loaded and otherwise display a custom alternative element.`... perhaps the OP doesn't need to know especially WHY cors prevents this and instead just needs a solution to the image loading check.

Comment: Is there a way to check for a CSS background image too (like in my CSS example)? Edit: I believe I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/16503617